# Search for event by place

Tags: facebook-graph-api

how can i use  graph api search for event by place. from this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event)

,Event has a field name place. I want to do something like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=event&place.id=xxx
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=event&place.name=xxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to "search" for events, you should be able to use the events endpoint: `/place-id/events`

If that does not work, try it with a Page.

Comment: thanks, this answer my question. but one more thing, if i have multiple place-id, do i need to do a 'batch' request or it has other way to do multiple ids request

Comment: you CAN do a batch request. they are just a way to use several api calls together, in a faster way.